# How can I repeatedly play a sound while a javascript alert message is up and stop it when the alert message is dismissed?

Tags: javascript, audio, alert

How can I repeatedly play a sound while a javascript alert message is up and stop it when the alert message is dismissed?

I already have an HTML5 sound element on the page.

I've tried:

```
while(alert("foobar alert!"))
{ document.getElementById('foobarTune').play();};
```

to no avail.

I know I can just do:

```
document.getElementById('foobarTune').play();
alert("foobar alert!")
```

to get it to run before the alert once.

My main concern is to get it to run during the alert and then have it repeat while the alert box is up. And stop when alert box is dismissed by the user.

Comment: While I can't answer the question, it seems worth noting that this would be incredibly annoying to me. And would likely make me quickly dismiss the alert/warning/whatever without bothering to read too closely, just to turn off the noise.

Comment: I'm using it for a timer function on my hobby website: voodooroo.com You can see it in action on the bottom "Timer (secs)" button. So for a timer it is pretty reasonable to think the user would expect an alert. I kid you not, in my question I was going to add that I am not looking for opinions on if it is annoying or not. I only mention this now because it's ironic that I actually got a comment about that.

Comment: To be fair, I'd have still commented if you *had* explicitly said you're not interested in hearing about it. Incidentally, though, given that you considered adding that disclaimer to the question, and that it was my first thought once I read the question, have you (objectively/critically) considered whether or not it's a good and appropriate UI feature?

Comment: Yes. Besides after testing it looks like Safari and Firefox don't let you loop HTML5 audio. Chrome it is working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using html 5 to play the audio. See the loop attribute.
Then just call stop() on the line after the alert(). alert() blocks script execution, so it will work.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Note: stop() didn't work. I looked it up. HTML5 spec uses the method pause();

Answer (score 2):

`alert` is a blocking call; statement after it won't execute until the alert box has been dismissed.

You would need to start a loop using `setTimeout` to play your sound before the call to `alert`.  The, once the call to `alert` completes, you could remove your timer / task.